# How do I run a script on Linux just by double clicking it

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have a script written (which are basically the commands for the terminal for Ubuntu) on a file. Yes, the code starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

How do I run this script just by double clicking it? It can be run using the terminal but I want to make it more accessible through my desktop.

I was just trying to mimic a *.bat file on windows. A *.bat file on windows contains series of scripts operable on command prompt and executable just by double clicking on it.

Comment: What window manager are you using (e.g. gnome, kde, etc..)?  Are you clicking on the name in a file manager window? I assume you're double-clicking an icon representing the file on the desktop or in a file browser, and not just clicking the filename in a terminal window (particularly because you indicate something actually happens).

Comment: Assuming you're using GTK, check this out http://askubuntu.com/a/664272

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Linux so should be asked on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @rob Yes, you can close this question here. I would copy it to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Hit `Alt+F2`, type `dconf-editor` and hit ``Enter.
- In dconfg-editor goto: `org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences`
- Click on `executable-text-activation` and from drop down menu select:

launch: to launch scripts as programs.

OR

ask: to ask what to do via a dialog.

Close `dconf-editor` Thats it!

Comment: Entering: dconf-editor and hitting enter doesn't do anything. I am using Linux Ubuntu16.04

Comment: check this link then http://askubuntu.com/questions/605965/gedit-does-not-launch-as-root-critical-file-log-c-error-no-gksu-probl

Comment: Can you explain it here. I cant understand whats there. I just want it to be an executable script that runs just by double clicking it.

Comment: install `dconf-editor` by doing this command `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Comment: Nice answer +1, but I found that when it uses "launch" it runs in the background so you can't see what is going on. I wanted it to run in a terminal - so if you select "ask" then it asks you to run in a terminal or just open it - selecting run in terminal does as it says which I found useful : )

Comment: The executable-text-activation is not a  nautilus option on Debian bookworm.

Answer (score 4):

Source https://askubuntu.com/a/286651/113065

Edit -> preferences -> Behavior -> Executable Text Files = Run ...

It should run, but you can't see output.

Comment: is there a way to configure ubuntu to show the output?

Comment: @bjubes drag the file into a terminal window and press enter

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way, mostly for developers, is to create self-contained desktop launchers. The idea is to use a launcher that includes a tag under which there is the script; the launcher executes a command that:

1. put the script into a temporary file
2. run the script which deletes itself

Of course, the script should delete itself, for this reason, it's a good practice to start the script with `rm $0`. Note that if the script needs to read the script itself, you will need to use `rm $0` somewhere else...

You can use the following example stolen from [my project](https://github.com/00sapo/launch_assistance):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Launch Assistance
Comment=A simple app to setup remote assistance
Exec=ttt=/tmp/$(date +"%s%N").sh; tail -n+$(awk '/^#__SCRIPT__#/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' %k) %k > $ttt ; sh $ttt;
Icon=computer
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Internet;Utilities;Administration;Settings;

#__SCRIPT__#
rm "$0"
# Put here the script
# note that if the script needs to read $0, you will have to edit it
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer. I guess it is worth mentioning that a more straightforward version of this is to create one script file, and one .desktop file that references the script in its Exec field, and for me personally, that would be the best answer on this page.

Comment: That would involve two files, while the question effectively ask for one single file. The solution I proposed can be set up by a developer and it will work for any user out of the box, without any permission/setting change needed.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to penalize this technique for using "two files". A creator, using this technique, only writes one file. The distribution of this technique only sends one file. The end-user of this technique only interacts with one file. They are all the same file! The fact a temporary gets created during the use seems like a very innocuous implementation detail, for the large majority of people interested in this question, even, potentially, the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it an executable file, either use `chmod +x <filename>` or go into the file properties and set it there.

Comment: It is executable (I have already done that). But when I try to open it, it opens in editing mode.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and these solutions do not work anymore. As they say, it will only open in the selected application and there is no option to change the application to execute or terminal. Does anyone have a new solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open nautilus
2. Behavior tab
3. Executable Text files -> Ask each time
4. Profit

[Source](https://itqna.net/questions/37789/run-script-shell-double-click-ubuntu). Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just Ububtu can not auto run via Terminal and I don't know way to do this. In option Open With not show terminal to select, too