# Run Jupyter-notebook on boot on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, server, jupyter-notebook, startup, boot

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine with anaconda installed,
And I want it to launch Jupyter-notebook on startup with the correct configuration file (ip address, port, password,...)

This configuration is specified in /home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

When I'm logged as *user* and in the home directory(/home/user/) it does launch the correct config file.

But when using the command

```
jupyter-notebook
```

During startup with rc.local or using crontab it's doesn't load my configuration file, and have not the correct running directory.

Comment: I tried on Ubuntu 20.04 and it was resolved when I activated the respective conda environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very similar question and answer: [How to start ipython notebook server at boot as daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297741/how-to-start-ipython-notebook-server-at-boot-as-daemon)

You could add the following line to your `/etc/rc.local` file

```
su <username> -c "jupyter notebook --config=/location/of/your/config/file/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py --no-browser --notebook-dir=/location/of/yournotebooks" &
```

e.g.

```
su simon -c "jupyter notebook --config=/home/simon/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py --no-browser --notebook-dir=/home/simon/notebooks" &
```

---

`su <username> -c` makes sure that the notebook is not executed as root but with the specified user account.``

`--config` and `--notebook-dir` specify the location of your config file and your notebook folder (http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html)

---

For systems using `systemd` (Ubuntu 16 and later) the following approach also works:

- Create a service file in `/etc/systemd/system/`, e.g. `jupyter.service` with the following content (replace `YourUserName` with your username)

  ```
  [Unit]
  After=network.service

  [Service]
  ExecStart=jupyter notebook
  User=YourUserName

  [Install]
  WantedBy=default.target
  ```
- Enable the service with `sudo systemctl enable jupyter.service`
- Start the service with `sudo systemctl start jupyter.service`

You should set a password for your Jupyter server because you won't have access to the token.

Comment: @CarlosSouza Can you post a few more details as a separate question?

Comment: Sure: I did exact as you described:
- created a `/etc/rc.local`
- included the line as you showed
on an Ubuntu 18.04, EC2 instance. Nothing happens.

Comment: @CarlosSouza: Best to open a new question or discuss it in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205822/run-jupyter-notebook-on-boot-on-ubuntu

Comment: @CarlosSouza: Can you try to execute your `/etc/rc.local` file via and check if there are any error messages?

Comment: @CésarArquero: Just got a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

this one worked for me. Put this in your `/etc/rc.local`.

```
sudo -u <username> nohup /home/<username>/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --no-browser --notebook-dir=/home/<username>/<notebook_dir>&
```

In my case, `/etc/rc.local` is not available at the first time, so you need to create this first. Then, make it executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Here is the content of my `rc.local` look like.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo -u my_username nohup /home/my_username/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --no-browser --notebook-dir=/home/my_username/notebook&

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in ubuntu 20.04 the "/etc/rc.local" way didn't work. I've solved in two steps: (1) creating and executable file that work just with double click or enter; and (2) addind the execution to startup applications in gnome.

Here is in detail:

1. Create the file in the place you want and add executable option. Here is the one line of code to create the file in the USER folder: `cd /home/USER & touch jupyterlab.sh & sudo chmod u+x jupyterlab.sh`
2. Add the corresponding execution excript to the file. In my case I'm running jupyter-lab (locate the program with `which jupyter-lab`), with an ip and port as I'm using it as server.

Here is what the file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab --ip 192.168.1.32 --port 9000 --no-browser & exit
```

3. (optional) Make the file executable also by double click and enter goint to preferences in dolphin ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044798/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-linux-just-by-double-clicking-it)).
4. Add the file and .sh extension to the startup aplications.

[image]

May be it seems long, but it has the advantages of getting an executable file that can initialize (or not) just with a few clicks.

Comment: In my case, it took a little bit of time to start up script to start jupyter, but this solution really works really well. I guess the lag time depends on the computer. This solution easy to execute and importantly does not involve the use of `sudo` privileges. So less likely to mess up the system upon a silly mistake. For making the script executable `chmod +x jupyterlab.sh` will also do.

Comment: I had a few suggestions to improve the answer but could not add them in, because the "edit queue is full". Could you please add them from this link: https://pastebin.com/QcPfVcKG